# Extern "C" explicit type error in Visual Studio 2015, DLL test code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, extern

I am trying to compile a very basic set of code to test functionality of using a VS15 C++-made DLL in R. I followed this tutorial: https://erpcoder.blog/2016/06/15/how-to-develop-a-c-dll-for-r-in-visual-studio-2015/

stdafx.h:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             
#include <windows.h>

extern “C” __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl foo(double *in, double *out);
```

DLL_Test.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void foo(double *in, double *out)
{

    double value = in[0] * 2;

    out[0] = value;

}
```

VS15 gives me the following errors corresponding to stdafx.h:

```
explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    
expected a ';'
```

---

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *really* have smart quotes in your code: `extern “C”`?

I suspect you probably *do* because the site you're cut'n'pasting the code from also has them (and quite a few, probably a good reason to look for *another* site, in my opinion, but you could equally just use their code provided you're happy to fix the bugs in it).

You should replace them with dumber (but far more acceptable) quotes:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl foo(double *in, double *out);
//     ^ ^
//     Here
```

---

As an aside, I have left a comment on the site suggesting they fix the issue (currently awaiting moderation).